# Feign with zookeeper succeeds with normal app but fails with JUnit

Tags: junit, apache-zookeeper, spring-cloud-netflix, feign

I use the zookeeper as the service register, and that's my problem: when I run it directly as a spring boot application it succeeds, instead when I use the junit to test it, it fails.

The pom dependencies as as below:

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-zookeeper-discovery</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-feign</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-ribbon</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <!--<dependency>-->
        <!--<groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>-->
        <!--<artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-hystrix</artifactId>-->
    <!--</dependency>-->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
        <artifactId>httpcore</artifactId>
        <version>4.4</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
<dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-dependencies</artifactId>
            <version>Camden.RELEASE</version>
            <type>pom</type>
            <scope>import</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</dependencyManagement>
```

The Feign Code is as below:

```
@Configuration
public class BeanConfig {
    @Bean
    @LoadBalanced
    RestTemplate restTemplate() {
        return new RestTemplate();
    }
}

@FeignClient(value = "walletbackstage")
public interface IWalletBackstageClient {
    @RequestMapping(value = "/walletRate/getWalletRateByType/{type}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    ResponseResult getWalletRateType(@PathVariable(name = "type") Integer type);
}
```

The run code is as below:

```
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableDiscoveryClient
@EnableFeignClients
public class App {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(App.class, args);
    }
}
```

The junit code is as below:

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest
public class TestClientTest {

    @Autowired
    IWalletBackstageClient walletBackstageClient;

    @Test
    public void testFegin() {
        Object walletRateType = walletBackstageClient.getWalletRateType(1);
        System.out.println(walletRateType);
    }
}
```

The Exception is the following:

```
2017-07-13 11:39:55.182  WARN 9976 --- [lletbackstage-1] s.c.a.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext : Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'dependenciesBasedLoadBalancer' defined in org.springframework.cloud.zookeeper.discovery.ZookeeperRibbonClientConfiguration: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [com.netflix.loadbalancer.ILoadBalancer]: Factory method 'dependenciesBasedLoadBalancer' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.NullPointerException

    com.netflix.hystrix.exception.HystrixRuntimeException: IWalletBackstageClient#getWalletRateType(Integer) failed and no fallback available.
        at com.netflix.hystrix.AbstractCommand$22.call(AbstractCommand.java:805)
        at com.netflix.hystrix.AbstractCommand$22.call(AbstractCommand.java:790)
        at rx.internal.operators.OperatorOnErrorResumeNextViaFunction$4.onError(OperatorOnErrorResumeNextViaFunction.java:140)
        at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeDoOnEach$DoOnEachSubscriber.onError(OnSubscribeDoOnEach.java:87)
        at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeDoOnEach$DoOnEachSubscriber.onError(OnSubscribeDoOnEach.java:87)
        at com.netflix.hystrix.AbstractCommand$DeprecatedOnFallbackHookApplication$1.onError(AbstractCommand.java:1470)
        at com.netflix.hystrix.AbstractCommand$FallbackHookApplication$1.onError(AbstractCommand.java:1395)
        at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeDoOnEach$DoOnEachSubscriber.onError(OnSubscribeDoOnEach.java:87)
        at rx.observers.Subscribers$5.onError(Subscribers.java:230)
        at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeThrow.call(OnSubscribeThrow.java:44)
        at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeThrow.call(OnSubscribeThrow.java:28)
        at rx.Observable.unsafeSubscribe(Observable.java:10211)
        at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeDefer.call(OnSubscribeDefer.java:51)
        at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeDefer.call(OnSubscribeDefer.java:35)
        at rx.Observable.unsafeSubscribe(Observable.java:10211)
        at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeDoOnEach.call(OnSubscribeDoOnEach.java:41)
        at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeDoOnEach.call(OnSubscribeDoOnEach.java:30)
        at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeLift.call(OnSubscribeLift.java:48)
        at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeLift.call(OnSubscribeLift.java:30)
        at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeLift.call(OnSubscribeLift.java:48)
        at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeLift.call(OnSubscribeLift.java:30)
        at rx.Observable.unsafeSubscribe(Observable.java:10211)
        at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeDoOnEach.call(OnSubscribeDoOnEach.java:41)
        at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeDoOnEach.call(OnSubscribeDoOnEach.java:30)
        at rx.Observable.unsafeSubscribe(Observable.java:10211)
        at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeDoOnEach.call(OnSubscribeDoOnEach.java:41)
        at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeDoOnEach.call(OnSubscribeDoOnEach.java:30)
        at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeLift.call(OnSubscribeLift.java:48)
        at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeLift.call(OnSubscribeLift.java:30)
        at rx.Observable.unsafeSubscribe(Observable.java:10211)
        at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeDoOnEach.call(OnSubscribeDoOnEach.java:41)
        at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeDoOnEach.call(OnSubscribeDoOnEach.java:30)
        at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeLift.call(OnSubscribeLift.java:48)
        at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeLift.call(OnSubscribeLift.java:30)
        at rx.Observable.unsafeSubscribe(Observable.java:10211)
        at rx.internal.operators.OperatorOnErrorResumeNextViaFunction$4.onError(OperatorOnErrorResumeNextViaFunction.java:142)
        at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeDoOnEach$DoOnEachSubscriber.onError(OnSubscribeDoOnEach.java:87)
        at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeDoOnEach$DoOnEachSubscriber.onError(OnSubscribeDoOnEach.java:87)
        at com.netflix.hystrix.AbstractCommand$HystrixObservableTimeoutOperator$3.onError(AbstractCommand.java:1173)
        at rx.internal.operators.OperatorSubscribeOn$1$1.onError(OperatorSubscribeOn.java:59)
        at rx.observers.Subscribers$5.onError(Subscribers.java:230)
        at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeDoOnEach$DoOnEachSubscriber.onError(OnSubscribeDoOnEach.java:87)
        at rx.observers.Subscribers$5.onError(Subscribers.java:230)
        at com.netflix.hystrix.AbstractCommand$DeprecatedOnRunHookApplication$1.onError(AbstractCommand.java:1429)
        at com.netflix.hystrix.AbstractCommand$ExecutionHookApplication$1.onError(AbstractCommand.java:1360)
        at rx.observers.Subscribers$5.onError(Subscribers.java:230)
        at rx.observers.Subscribers$5.onError(Subscribers.java:230)
        at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeThrow.call(OnSubscribeThrow.java:44)
        at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeThrow.call(OnSubscribeThrow.java:28)
        at rx.Observable.unsafeSubscribe(Observable.java:10211)
        at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeDefer.call(OnSubscribeDefer.java:51)
        at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeDefer.call(OnSubscribeDefer.java:35)
        at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeLift.call(OnSubscribeLift.java:48)
        at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeLift.call(OnSubscribeLift.java:30)
        at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeLift.call(OnSubscribeLift.java:48)
        at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeLift.call(OnSubscribeLift.java:30)
        at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeLift.call(OnSubscribeLift.java:48)
        at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeLift.call(OnSubscribeLift.java:30)
        at rx.Observable.unsafeSubscribe(Observable.java:10211)
        at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeDefer.call(OnSubscribeDefer.java:51)
        at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeDefer.call(OnSubscribeDefer.java:35)
        at rx.Observable.unsafeSubscribe(Observable.java:10211)
        at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeDoOnEach.call(OnSubscribeDoOnEach.java:41)
        at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeDoOnEach.call(OnSubscribeDoOnEach.java:30)
        at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeLift.call(OnSubscribeLift.java:48)
        at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeLift.call(OnSubscribeLift.java:30)
        at rx.Observable.unsafeSubscribe(Observable.java:10211)
        at rx.internal.operators.OperatorSubscribeOn$1.call(OperatorSubscribeOn.java:94)
        at com.netflix.hystrix.strategy.concurrency.HystrixContexSchedulerAction$1.call(HystrixContexSchedulerAction.java:56)
        at com.netflix.hystrix.strategy.concurrency.HystrixContexSchedulerAction$1.call(HystrixContexSchedulerAction.java:47)
        at com.netflix.hystrix.strategy.concurrency.HystrixContexSchedulerAction.call(HystrixContexSchedulerAction.java:69)
        at rx.internal.schedulers.ScheduledAction.run(ScheduledAction.java:55)
        at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
    Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'dependenciesBasedLoadBalancer' defined in org.springframework.cloud.zookeeper.discovery.ZookeeperRibbonClientConfiguration: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [com.netflix.loadbalancer.ILoadBalancer]: Factory method 'dependenciesBasedLoadBalancer' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.NullPointerException
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:599)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1128)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1023)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:510)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:482)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:197)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:751)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:861)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:541)
        at org.springframework.cloud.context.named.NamedContextFactory.createContext(NamedContextFactory.java:110)
        at org.springframework.cloud.context.named.NamedContextFactory.getContext(NamedContextFactory.java:79)
        at org.springframework.cloud.context.named.NamedContextFactory.getInstance(NamedContextFactory.java:115)
        at org.springframework.cloud.netflix.ribbon.SpringClientFactory.getInstance(SpringClientFactory.java:111)
        at org.springframework.cloud.netflix.ribbon.SpringClientFactory.getClientConfig(SpringClientFactory.java:65)
        at org.springframework.cloud.netflix.feign.ribbon.LoadBalancerFeignClient.getClientConfig(LoadBalancerFeignClient.java:78)
        at org.springframework.cloud.netflix.feign.ribbon.LoadBalancerFeignClient.execute(LoadBalancerFeignClient.java:62)
        at org.springframework.cloud.zookeeper.discovery.dependency.DependencyFeignClientAutoConfiguration$1.execute(DependencyFeignClientAutoConfiguration.java:81)
        at feign.SynchronousMethodHandler.executeAndDecode(SynchronousMethodHandler.java:97)
        at feign.SynchronousMethodHandler.invoke(SynchronousMethodHandler.java:76)
        at feign.hystrix.HystrixInvocationHandler$1.run(HystrixInvocationHandler.java:108)
        at com.netflix.hystrix.HystrixCommand$2.call(HystrixCommand.java:299)
        at com.netflix.hystrix.HystrixCommand$2.call(HystrixCommand.java:295)
        at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeDefer.call(OnSubscribeDefer.java:46)
        ... 26 more
    Caused by: org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [com.netflix.loadbalancer.ILoadBalancer]: Factory method 'dependenciesBasedLoadBalancer' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.NullPointerException
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:189)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:588)
        ... 51 more
    Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
        at org.springframework.cloud.zookeeper.discovery.ZookeeperServerList.getServers(ZookeeperServerList.java:80)
        at org.springframework.cloud.zookeeper.discovery.ZookeeperServerList.getInitialListOfServers(ZookeeperServerList.java:68)
        at org.springframework.cloud.zookeeper.discovery.dependency.DependenciesBasedLoadBalancer.<init>(DependenciesBasedLoadBalancer.java:52)
        at org.springframework.cloud.zookeeper.discovery.ZookeeperRibbonClientConfiguration.dependenciesBasedLoadBalancer(ZookeeperRibbonClientConfiguration.java:88)
        at org.springframework.cloud.zookeeper.discovery.ZookeeperRibbonClientConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$9f4ce39c.CGLIB$dependenciesBasedLoadBalancer$6(<generated>)
        at org.springframework.cloud.zookeeper.discovery.ZookeeperRibbonClientConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$9f4ce39c$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$329718a4.invoke(<generated>)
        at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invokeSuper(MethodProxy.java:228)
        at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassEnhancer$BeanMethodInterceptor.intercept(ConfigurationClassEnhancer.java:356)
        at org.springframework.cloud.zookeeper.discovery.ZookeeperRibbonClientConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$9f4ce39c.dependenciesBasedLoadBalancer(<generated>)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:162)
        ... 52 more

    2017-07-13 11:39:55.224  INFO 9976 --- [       Thread-5] c.n.l.PollingServerListUpdater           : Shutting down the Executor Pool for PollingServerListUpdater
    2017-07-13 11:39:55.226  INFO 9976 --- [       Thread-4] o.s.w.c.s.GenericWebApplicationContext   : Closing org.springframework.web.context.support.GenericWebApplicationContext@769d513: startup date [Thu Jul 13 11:39:48 CST 2017]; parent: org.springframework.context.annotation.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext@62e70ea3
    2017-07-13 11:39:55.229  INFO 9976 --- [       Thread-4] o.s.c.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor  : Stopping beans in phase 0
    2017-07-13 11:39:55.236  INFO 9976 --- [tor-Framework-0] o.a.c.f.imps.CuratorFrameworkImpl        : backgroundOperationsLoop exiting
    2017-07-13 11:39:55.253  INFO 9976 --- [       Thread-4] org.apache.zookeeper.ZooKeeper           : Session: 0x15caffd3955c4d0 closed
    2017-07-13 11:39:55.253  INFO 9976 --- [ain-EventThread] org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxn          : EventThread shut down
    2017-07-13 11:39:55.254  INFO 9976 --- [       Thread-4] s.c.a.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext : Closing org.springframework.context.annotation.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext@3f36e8d1: startup date [Thu Jul 13 11:39:50 CST 2017]; parent: org.springframework.web.context.support.GenericWebApplicationContext@769d513
    Disconnected from the target VM, address: '127.0.0.1:63579', transport: 'socket'

    Process finished with exit code -1
```

Comment: code reformatting, grammar/syntax corrections

Comment: useless parts removed, title improvements